# sling:OsgiConfig Node changes are not applying in Felix config manager

Tags: osgi, aem, apache-felix

Am trying to make the sling:OsgiConfig nodes as per this [link](http://aempodcast.com/2016/infrastucture/best-practice-treat-osgi-configurations-code/) for **Apache Sling Service User Mapper** and **Apache Sling Service User Mapper Service Amendment** Felix configuration, But those are not reflecting into Felix console, is there anything am missing for these nodes.?

Note : below node changes are reflecting for the as per the link.

> org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.security.authentication.external.impl.DefaultSyncHandler.config

Nodes which are not reflecting into Felix configuration.

> org.apache.sling.serviceusermapping.impl.ServiceUserMapperImpl
>   org.apache.sling.serviceusermapping.impl.ServiceUserMapperImpl.amended.config

[image]
[image]

Comment: @ ub1k Thanks, this worked for me `org.apache.sling.serviceusermapping.impl.ServiceUserMapperImpl.amended-test-campaign-system-user.config`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing you need to do is give the multibound config item a specific unique name.
e.g.

`org.apache.sling.serviceusermapping.impl.ServiceUserMapperImpl.amended-custom`
mind the "custom" part.. this one has to be a unique string.

you'd see that happening if you only added your custom ammended config entry through the /system/console/configMgr